# Add button row for plugin JQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am using the plugin "DataTables" and I'm wanting to add an image by line, that when the user clicks, call another url.

I followed the examples of www.datatables.net but is giving the below error:

DataTables warning (table id = 'myDataTable'): Requested unknown parameter '4' from the data source for row 0.

Records are shown on the screen

```
<h2>Index</h2>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var oTable = $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "AjaxHandler",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",   
            "aoColumns": [
                        { "mDataProp": "ID", "bSortable": false },
                        { "mDataProp": "Nome", "sTitle": "Identificação do produto" },
                        { "mDataProp": "Address", "sTitle": "Descrição do produto" },
                        { "mDataProp": "Town" },
                        { "fnRender": function (o) {return '<a href=/Produto/Detalhar/' + o.aData[0] + '>' + 'More' + '</a>';}} 
            ],
        });
    });
</script>


<table id="myDataTable" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Company name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Town</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really know datatable (not enough), but you should try this way: {not sure mDataProp is deprecated or not}

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var oTable = $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "AjaxHandler",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",   
            "aoColumns": [
                        { "mData": "ID", "bSortable": false },
                        { "mData": "Nome", "sTitle": "Identificação do produto" },
                        { "mData": "Address", "sTitle": "Descrição do produto" },
                        { "mData": "Town" },
                        {   "mData": null,
                    "bSortable": false,
            "mRender": function (o) {return '<a href=/Produto/Detalhar/' + o.aData[0] + '>' + 'More' + '</a>';}
            }   
            ]
        });
    });
```

Be sure your data feet with you column declaration, you should have as ajax response a json with datas ID, Nome, Address and Town.
If your first data is id not ID, you would get an error i think.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using dataTables version 1.10.0-dev and the accepted solution does not work for me, because o.aData is undefined. Instead I have all the properties of the json objects that I'm returning server side in o. So this is my solution:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var oTable = $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "AjaxHandler",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "ID", "bSortable": false },
            { "mData": "Nome", "sTitle": "Identificação do produto" },
            { "mData": "Address", "sTitle": "Descrição do produto" },
            { "mData": "Town" },
            {
                "mData": null,
                "bSortable": false,
                "mRender": function (o) { return '<a href=/Produto/Detalhar/' + o.Id + '>' + 'More' + '</a>'; }
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

I don't know if this depends on the new version of dataTables or from others configurations (but my table is configured in the same manner ...).

Comment: Hi, this code is work this url http://www.flexgestor.com.br/CA, and dataTable version is 1.9.4 @Daniele Armanasco